# PlotMarkers doesn't inherit PlotStyle when first argument to Graphics isn't a list

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug fixed in 12.0**

---

Could somebody explain, why `Circle` does not inherit the `PlotStyle` of the plot when used as `PlotMarkers`? Here is an example:

```
l1 = RandomInteger[100, {20, 2}]
cross = Graphics[{Line[{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}], Line[{{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]}];
circle = Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]];
ListPlot[l1, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotMarkers -> {cross, .03}]
ListPlot[l1, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotMarkers -> {circle, .03}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This seem to work as expected, but the only difference is that Graphics is given a list of primitives:

```
circle1 = Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}];
ListPlot[l1, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotMarkers -> {circle1, .03}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just look at the FullForm[] for both ...

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, still not getting it...

Comment: I'm editing the title because `Graphics[Line[{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}]]` shows the same behavior when used as plotmarker

Comment: @belisarius thanks, much better.

Comment: @Ajasja Note that `cross = Graphics[Line[{{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}}]];
ListPlot[l1, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotMarkers -> {cross, .03}]` also ignores the `PlotStyle`. So the problem is in curly brackets, try `cross = Graphics[{Line[{{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}}]}];
ListPlot[l1, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotMarkers -> {cross, .03}]`.

Comment: `ListPlot[l1, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]], 0.03}][[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]]` seems the generated `Inset`s are all that is changed, with `{}` around `Circle` `Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Thickness[Large]` is prepended to the `Graphics` in the Inset

Comment: @ssch Yes, that's why the one with ´{}´ works as expected. Do you think I can tag this as a bug? Or is this somehow the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Ajasja I think it's a bug too

Comment: This seems to be fixed in v12.0.

Answer (score 5):

After reading the documentation for `PlotStyle` and `Graphics` I have the following hyopthesis:

`PlotStyle` tries to apply a graphics directive to the object `circle`, but as it is written in your example, `circle` is syntactically incorrect for accepting the directive. The syntax for applying a graphics directive to a graphics primitive must be of the form:

```
Graphics[{*directive1*,*directive2*, ..., *primative*[*co-ords,etc*]}]
```

I.e. The `{}` may need to be in place to allow `PlotStyle` to impart the directive to the object.

E.g. if `circle` is defined as

```
circle = Graphics[{Opacity[.1], Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}];
```

The resulting `PlotMarkers` will have `Thick` outlines *and* `Opacity[.1]`

This is consistent with composite primitives and single primitives (e.g. your `cross` and `circle`, respectively) being treated in the same fashion by `Plot`. In which case it is not a bug, just strict syntax.