# How to keep markers as dots in a joined ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, marker

Consider the following typical interactive sequence.  First I produce a `ListPlot`:

[image]

OK, not bad, but I want those dots to be bigger, and also joined.  First, I make the dots bigger, like this:

[image]

Good.  Next, to join the dots, I do this:

[image]

Aaaarrrrrgh!  The dots disappeared!  Why???  Don't they know *anything* about usability at WRI?

I have tried to achieve the desired effect in a bazillion ways, and they all fail for one reason or another: either the dots no longer look like dots (but rather like diamonds, squares, triangles), or they are no longer the same color as the lines joining them, or something else...

So my question is: how can I achieve the simple effect of several plots of (distinctly visible) dots joined by lines, and each plot of a different, but uniform, color?

I also have a meta-question: The frustration illustrated by the interaction above is entirely typical of my experience with *Mathematica*, since day 1.  I used to think that the reason why I had such difficulty getting the simplest things done with *Mathematica* was that I just didn't know it well enough...  But this problem has persisted over the years, with hardly any improvement, even though I've devoted considerable effort to learning more and more about *Mathematica*.  I have been using *Mathematica* now for about 20 years (!), and I *still* struggle *for hours at a time* with trivialities like this one.  This makes me wonder whether these difficulties are really more a reflection with a fundamental flaw in some aspect of *Mathematica*'s design (one that somehow makes [conceptually simple things](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/looking-for-equivalent-of-minorticks-none) turn out to be disproportionately difficult).  Sure, when one is starting out with some new software simple things may take a long time to accomplish, but *Mathematica* is the only software that I've been using for more than, say 4-5 years, and that I still have to struggle with for hours to get simple things to work (and very often I just have to give up with)...

Comment: About your meta-question, there was identical discussion here about something similar but I cand find it. There was no conclusion :) Some find those issues "features" the others "bugs". I believe the oryginal discussion was about not plotting automatically alle the values for given domain.

Comment: I would be surprised if anyone found the fact that `Joined -> True, Mesh -> All` draws every point in blue instead of the corresponding line's colour to be a "feature" and not a "bug".

Comment: @RahulNarain In this case I would call it bug, but it is not always so obvious, there are many different "features" out there :).

Comment: fyi, can also use the new command `ListLinePlot` for this. No difference for this case. `ListLinePlot[data, ImageSize -> 700, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qzu1B.png)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `PlotMarkers` option is designed to handle this problem. Here are two very simple ways to do it using that option.

```
data = Table[Table[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], {k, {1, 2, 3}}];

ListPlot[data,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}]
```

[image: plot.1]

The above solution has a drawback: there can be a slight misalignment of the markers, because they're rendered as text. See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/3066) for a detailed discussion.

```
ListPlot[data,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> Graphics@{Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled@0.01]}]
```

[image: plot.2]

Note: it might seem that wrapping `Disk` with `List` is unnecessary, but that is not the case. Without the wrapper, the points will alll be black. See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19002/3066) for more detail.

Answer (score 13):

This is a duplicate but I can't find it, meanwhile:

```
ListPlot[Table[Table[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], {k, {1, 2, 3}}], 
         PlotStyle -> PointSize@.01, Joined -> True
        ] /.  Line[x_, y___] :> {Point[x], Line[x, y]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Once again, I feel some remorse after choosing one of two excellent answers...

Comment: @kjo I think you have chosen well, I would accept m_goldberg's solution too. Modifying `PlotMarkes` is neatter then postprocessing :)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a low-level solution for this problem which guarantees exact positioning of graphics primitives:

```
data = Table[Table[{x, Sin[k x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], {k, 3}];

Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[1]@@ #2, Line@#1, PointSize[Medium], Point@#1} &, data], 
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: Very simple, and very cool!

Answer (score 7):

Quick-and-dirty:

```
data = Table[Table[{x, Sin[k x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], {k, 3}];
Show[
 ListPlot[data, Joined -> True (* add other options here *)],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Setting the colors of the dots independently is easy:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, Joined -> True (* add other options here *)],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Medium], Gray}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
data = Table[Sin[k x], {k, 3}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
ListLinePlot[data,  Mesh -> All]

MapThread[
  ListLinePlot[#, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> {PointSize@.012, #2}] &,
   {data, ColorData[1, "ColorList"]~Take~3}] // Show
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for finally correcting that nested `Table` thing!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I had not noticed that until reading your comment.  FWIW, the original was cut-and-pasted directly from the `Options>PlotStyle` section of the documentation page for `ListPlot`...

Comment: @kjo Sorry if I offended you; I did not mean to.  Rather, I couldn't believe that nobody before chyanog bothered to give the cleaner code for that.  Unfortunately the documentation examples are not always written in the best style IMO.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: oh, I took no offense at all, so no worries.  My comment was posted more as a curiosity than as anything else, and for those who, like me, may need to be reminded not to take the docs as holy scripture...  :)